Resolving InsufficientNotLockedBalanceException in Corda Token-SDK
I need to create a Corda workflow where I issue and transfer tokens to account sequentially within a single workflow. However, when I tried transferring tokens after issuing them, I faced an error called InsufficientNotLockedBalanceException.
I've tried utilizing both Database and In-memory token selection methods, but regardless of the approach, I keep encountering the same error message.
Has anyone faced a similar issue before, and if so, what steps did you take to resolve it? Any insights or guidance on how to effectively manage token balances and avoid this error would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!
Note : I'm using Corda 4.11 with token-sdk 1.2.5
Below error encountered during database token selection:
 com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.selection.InsufficientNotLockedBalanceException: Insufficient not locked spendable states identified for 10.00 TokenType(tokenIdentifier='USD', fractionDigits=2).
    at com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.selection.database.selector.DatabaseTokenSelection.selectTokens(DatabaseTokenSelection.kt:171) ~[tokens-workflows-1.2.5.jar:?]
    at com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.selection.api.Selector.generateMove(Selector.kt:184) ~[tokens-workflows-1.2.5.jar:?]

Below error encountered during In-memory token selection:
 com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.selection.InsufficientBalanceException: Insufficient spendable states identified for 10.00 TokenType(tokenIdentifier='USD', fractionDigits=2).
    at com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.selection.memory.services.VaultWatcherService.selectTokens(VaultWatcherService.kt:435) ~[tokens-workflows-1.4.0.jar:?]
    at com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.selection.memory.selector.LocalTokenSelector.selectTokens(LocalTokenSelector.kt:58) ~[tokens-workflows-1.4.0.jar:?]
    at com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.selection.api.Selector.generateMove(Selector.kt:184) ~[tokens-workflows-1.4.0.jar:?]
    at com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.selection.api.Selector.generateMove(Selector.kt:138) ~[tokens-workflows-1.4.0.jar:?]

